# how to insert toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() functions into an if condition?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, uppercase, lowercase

I created a page and want to display some data when the user types and search for a specific name of Region.

I set the function below inside a for loop function and it works, i.e: whenever the user types the name of a region listed into a JSON file I'm connecting to, some data are appended to the `tbody`:

```
if (region === textRegione) {
                    $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>"
                    );
                    $("#tabella").show();
                }
```

The problem is that the user has to write the name of the Region wit the first letter in uppercase and the rest of the word in lowercase. I want to use the functions `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` in order to tell the browser to display the info no matter which is the case of the letters.
I wrote the following ut it doesn't work:

```
if (region === textRegione && textRegione.toLowerCase() && textRegione.toUpperCase()) {
                    $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>"
                    );
                    $("#tabella").show();
                }
                ;
```

The info are still shown but only if the word is typed with first letter in uppercase and the rest in lowercase...

Comment: Could you just use `toLowerCase()` on every string you're comparing and then display the unmodified title-case text?

Answer (score 0):

Just lowercase or uppercase your search query and value.

For example;

```
if (region.toLowerCase() === textRegione.toLowerCase()) {
   $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + 
   tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");

   $("#tabella").show();
};
```

An alternative, you could use the [.seach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) function so regular expression will be available.
For example;

```
if (region.toLowerCase().search(textRegione.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
   $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + 
   tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");

   $("#tabella").show();
};
```